# How can the differences between two curvy graphs be described, when both graphs indicate a positive relationship between X & Y?

Tags: graphing-functions

[image: Two curvy graphs]

In both curves (C) and (D), with the increase of value x, dependent variable y increases. But these two curves have different shapes.

How will we describe the differences between the curve (C) and (D)? As both curves indicate a positive relationship between independent variable, x, and dependent variable, y, why/how do these two curves take different shapes?

I like to learn these differences in a descriptive manner. That means- without using any equation (if it is possible, or as much as possible), their differences will be described.

Comment: It is standard to call the first curve "concave" and the second curve "convex".

Comment: You could also consider their rates of change in _y_. C has a high rate of change in _y_ for low values of _x_, compared with D